# Using revolution slider with Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web, webpack

I am banging on my head to find out how to use Revolution Slider with Webpack. Our client has bought a theme using it and now, i need to merge it to our application.

I use Angular with Webpack and when run "element.show().revolution()", nothing shows up.

Could anyone please help me or give me another approach for my case?

Comment: Hi there, I have the same problem... Would you share a solution if you have found one?